# nginx redirect using /etc/hosts

Tags: nginx, proxy, hosts

I have a confusion and problem with doing maybe strange thing. I've got application, where we send a request at `http://somehost:9000/endpoint/x`. In `/etc/hosts` where is our app running we've got `123.123.123.123:somehost` mapping. But on our production environment we can't touch hosts file. So we've got create proxy on nginx. So.. Is it possible to request into nginx (`http://nginx:80/endpoint/x`) for example and he will do that hosts mapping inside? Additional things is that we have to add .p12 certificate (it can be copied straight to nginx directories) and body + HTTP headers from request which we send from application. I think that part with hosts mapping is mostly confusing me - I don't know how to make it.

```
server {
    listen              80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://somehost:9000;

    }
}
```

It is a idea about sample proxy, but how to make this host mapping from that given host?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to specify the IP address of the service in the Nginx configuration file?

Comment: Hm, what do you mean? Problem is that I can't send request directly to `123.123.123.123`, I have to request it by `somehost` and map DNS in hosts file `123.123.123.123:somehost`

Answer (score 1):

You cant' use /etc/hosts on server but you could use nginx upstream module. Like this

```
upstream somehost {
  server 123.123.123.123:9000;
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://somehost;

    }
}
```

Comment: inside "location /" you can add headers like "proxy_add_header Host somehost.com"

Comment: but.. Using it like that (even tried with adding somehost:8012 etc.) I've got still a: 
`2020/12/09 07:59:03 [error] 28#28: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "POST /endpoint HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://123.123.123.123:9000/", host: "localhost:8091"
172.17.0.1 - 00 [09/Dec/2020:07:59:03 +0000] "POST /endpoint p HTTP/1.1" 504 167 "-" "curl/7.29.0"`

For additional info - nginx is running on docker.

Comment: You should check connectivity between your nginx docker image and 123.123.123.123. Firewalls, routes, IP-address, etc. 504 - gateway timeout - 2 reasons - no connection between nginx and backend OR backend takes a long time to process your requests

Comment: My docker is running on machine where I can send a request to somehost when I've got `123.123.123.123 somehost` in my `/etc/hosts/` and I send it to `somehost:9000/x` (I can't send it straight through 123.123.123.123:9000/x`. So should I try to increase my timeout first, y? Then should I check firewalls on my machine or open some ports/etc. on nginx docker image?

Comment: At first - try straight curl request to http://123.123.123.123:9000 from your machine. If it works - next step is trying to curl it from docker image. Without nginx. Standard nginx timeout is 60 sec. If upstream needs more time - you could increase timeout. But usually it's not required.

Comment: Thanks! It increased a bit, and now nginx is returning 403 forbidden.

Comment: I forgot to add.. That I have to shot at `https` with some SSL certs.